# bash sort so that results are in numeric order as well as string order

Tags: regex, string, bash, compare

Let's say I was comparing two adjacent lines to each other after running `sort -u` on a file.  I find they both match n-characters over from the left side, then begin to disagree at some point, and where the disagreement begins, the first line had a digit "0" to "9".  The second line has a non-digit.  I want the two lines to swap positions.  Why do I want this?  Because the digit in the first line meand it is a longer number, and needs to go behind the other, so that these lines, regardless of the digit value, will rearrange from this:

```
xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.DD-xx.x.x.x  
xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.D-xx.x.x.x
```

to this:

```
xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.D-xx.x.x.x  
xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxx.DD-xx.x.x.x
```

And this:

```
1  
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9
```

becomes this:

```
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9  
10  
11  
12  
13  
14  
15
```

because it forces numeric values with the same number of digits to be
compared with each other, as those grouped from the left with more digits are moved behind those with fewer digits.

My logic might break down at some point, but until I can code it, I can't check the results returned.  So does anybody know how to do this in bash?

Answer (score 0):

`sort -g` (general numeric sort) should do the trick.